# Cannot use ampersand as argument in user defined command with optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments, ampersand

I'm trying to produce a command for an equation that may or may not be used inside an `align` element, and therefore sometimes needs a `&` next to the `=` to align the equation. I therefore defined the command `\newcommand{\optal}[1][=]{a #1 b}` so that when called as simply `\optal` it outputs the equation, but when called as `\optal[&=]` I can use the equation inside an align. The problem is that for some reason the command fails; it seems one cannot use `&` as a parameter. The problem goes away if I make the argument mandatory (ie, `\newcommand{\optal}[1]{a #1 b}`)

Here is the MWE. I'm using Miktex 2.9 and pdflatex.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    % new command
    \newcommand{\optal}[1][=]{a #1 b}
    %trying it out
    $\optal$ \\
    $\optal[ \neq ]$ \\
    % trying it out inside align
    \begin{align}
    \optal[=]
    \end{align}
    %so far, so good
    % trying it out with & as parameter
    \begin{align}
    \optal[&=]
    \end{align}
    % Fails with "Argument of \\optal has an extra } \end{align}"
    % Paragraph ended before \\optal was complete \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

Am I missing something? Can you think of a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protect it with braces

```
\optal[{&=}]
```

Note that you can add more symbols to the side of an equation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\optal}[1][=]{a #1 b}

\begin{document}
$\optal$ 
$\optal[ \neq ]$ 
\begin{align}
\optal
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\optal[{&=}]         & \optal[{&=}] + \int \\
\optal[{&=}] + \iint & \optal[{&=}] - \partial
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a simple workaround, I've ended up using it.

Answer (score 15):

You've found a dark corner in the alignment process. Let's see what happens.

1. When starting a cell in an alignment, TeX expands tokens in order to see whether `\omit` appears (it's used, for example, in `\multicolumn` for spanning columns).
2. The expansion of `\optal[&=]` is

   ```
   \@protected@testopt \optal \\optal {=}[&=]
   ```

   (note that `\\optal` is a single control sequence)
3. The expansion of `\@protected@testopt` is

   ```
   \ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@testopt \else \@x@protect #1\fi
   ```

   so `#1` is `\optal` (which is removed from the input stream)
4. The conditional is true, so what remains in the input stream is

   ```
   \@testopt \\optal {=}[&=]
   ```
5. The expansion of `\@testopt` is

   ```
   #1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1}{#1[{#2}]}
   ```

   so `#1` is `\\optal` and `#2` is `=` (the braces are stripped off); what remains in the input stream is

   ```
   \kernel@ifnextchar[{\\optal}{\\optal[{=}]}[&=]
   ```

Up to now no unexpandable token has been found, so TeX is still expanding tokens; the expansion of `\kernel@ifnextchar` starts with `\let` and now TeX determines that no `\omit` was present. Then TeX proceeds to build the alignment cell. However, it grabs only everything *up to the next `&` at the same level, so the contents of the cell is

```
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\\optal}{\\optal[{=}]}[
```

and no closing `]` for the optional argument is found in the cell. The error message says

```
Argument of \\optal has an extra }
```

because in the search for the closing `]` TeX find a closing brace (it would be too long to explain where it comes from).

With Sigur's workaround, what remains is

```
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\\optal}{\\optal[{=}]}[{&=}]
```

and now the `&` is not at the same level of grouping, so the cell is not terminated; TeX finds the `[` so it does

```
\\optal[{&=}]
```

and, since the expansion of `\\optal` is `[#1]->a #1 b` the braces around the argument are stripped off and

```
a &= b
```

is found, which terminates the cell at the right time.

***Wow!***

Comment: If I could I'd give you +10. I saw my solution cited on your dissertation. So do you confirm it?! lol It was right?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, of course. ;-)

Comment: Dark indeed, I found it weird that no other (sensible) argument could trigger the same error. Awesome explanation, it seems I have to learn TeX as well since it can show it's teeth occasionaly.

Answer (score 7):

You can hide the `&` from the argument scanner without having to put a `{}` group in every instance by using the `{\ifnum0='}` idiom used in all table macros. Note however that (unlike the explicit use of `{}` within the argument) this does introduce a `{}` group into the cell, which does not affect your example but could in principle (hence my modified example with `+`.  Hiding teh `&` automatically without introducing a `{}` mathord atom is possible but harder.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



% new command
\newcommand{\optal}{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\xoptcal}
\newcommand\xoptcal[1][=]{\ifnum0=`{\fi} +a #1 b }
%trying it out
$\optal$ \\
$\optal[ \neq ]$ \\
% trying it out inside align
\begin{align}
\optal[=]
\end{align}
%so far, so good
% trying it out with & as parameter
\begin{align}
\optal[&=]\\
+a&=b3\\
{}+a&=b3\\
\end{align}
% Fails with "Argument of \\optal has an extra } \end{align}"
% Paragraph ended before \\optal was complete \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed exactly what I had in mind when using the command, but given that I define such commands so often, and it's definition is so hackish, it would make them a bit messy to go through later.